# Running long report problem in Report server

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

i am trying to run few reports(MS Reporting server) that can be big if i set time period ALL, but also those report are getting error code 800708CA in RS log if i just set small amount of data.
Error code is:

> ERROR: Throwing
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ClosingRegisteredStreamException:
>   ,
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ClosingRegisteredStreamException:
>   An error occurred closing a registered stream. --->
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerHttpRuntimeClientDisconnectionException:
>   A client has disconnected from the Report Server Web service
>   application domain ReportServer_SSRS_0-3-131959013894837810. No
>   corrective action is required. An error code has been submitted to
>   ASP.NET to release the connection. The error code is 800708CA. --->
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: This network connection
>   does not exist. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800708CA)

What can i do to solve this error. Time out in RS is set to 1800 s, that is enough. Running the same report in MS SQL Studio in done in coupled of seconds.

Comment: Seems to be some form of timeout error based on google results.  [check this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/df516e5c-3799-4266-8afb-5d16400424ee/ssrs-excel-export-fails-for-large-dataset?forum=sqlreportingservices) for more ideas on timeouts that could be causing the issue. I would also check your connection to the report server and datasource.

Comment: Do you have any filters inside the dataset properties? Or do you have parameters dependent on the main dataset?

Comment: Yes i have input parameters, time period. Funny is that sometimes report opens and sometimes won't. TimeProcessing in Report server data base for the same report is so high